# How much light would pass through ice?

Tags: magic, worldbuilding-process, classical-elements, element, greenhouse-effect

I am writing a book in which a civilisation lives in the remnants of a giant crater with a dome of ice over the top. This crater is huge, I'm talking about 200 square miles huge, so this is a very large country with an "ice canopy", closing it in from the outside world. This would essentially make this a greenhouse. In this society, there is no technology or need to burn fossil fuels. I am wondering:

a. How thick would this "ice canopy" need to be to allow most light in?
b. What does sunlight passing through ice look like at varying thicknesses?

Keep in mind, that there is classical-elemental magic that exists in the kingdom, but the knowledge of what the canopy is made of is completely unknown to the population of the kingdom due to the height of the walls (about 7k meters tall). People in the kingdom speculate that the canopy is made of water, but no one can confirm for sure.

Thank you! This is my first post, and any answers or subsequent questions are appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please note we answer 1 question per post, and it would help if you showed what have you already found on your own. Our [help] explains better how to ask.

Comment: Such an ice canopy couldn't possibly exist, so I assume magic maintains both the edges of the crater and the canopy itself, so presumably the ice can also be as magically transparent as you might need?